# CSS only banner slider - Image hyperlink not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

```css
.zd-slider { position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin-top: 0px; }
.zd-slider img[id*="img"] {width:100%; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity:0; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}

/* set the width/height of the slideshow */
.zd-slider img#blank {display:block; width:100%; visibility:hidden;}

/* the slideshow */
.zd-slider #img_01 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;}
.zd-slider #img_02 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;}
.zd-slider #img_03 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s; }


@-webkit-keyframes autoplay {
  4%,33% {opacity:1;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
  0%,37%,100% {opacity:0;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}
}


@keyframes autoplay {
  4%,33% {opacity:1;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
  0%,37%,100% {opacity:0;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}
}

/* the slide timing indicator */
.zd-slider #slide {width:98px; height:5px; position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
-webkit-animation:slide 3s linear infinite; animation:slide linear 3s infinite;}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {left:-100px;}
  100% {left:100%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {left:-100px;}
  100% {left:100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="zd-container" id="zd-collection2"> <div class="zd-slider">

  <img id="blank" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> 
  
  <img id="img_01" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> 
  
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
  <img id="img_02" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /></a>
  
  <img id="img_03" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> <div id="slide"></div> </div> </div>
```

I'm using this slideshow format to display banners on an eBay store listing. I want to have the slides link to various pages in the store however I've tried to add a hyperlink in the traditional way (see "img_02") and had absolutely no luck making the slide clickable. I've seen similar questions on here and tried a few different "working" solutions but had no luck with any. If anyone could advise on how to solve this problem it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you dont have to support old IE's, use `opacity` instead of the `progid:` mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a z-index problem and also because you position your image absolutely, your link will have no height.

In the below, I have wrapped your images in spans and positioned that instead of the image (with the same class as the anchor so that also gets positioned) and added some z-index to your animation (comments in code).

```css
.zd-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.zd-slider .container { /* move this from image to new container span / link */
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}

.zd-slider img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* set the width/height of the slideshow */

.zd-slider #blank {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none; /* I added this in case it appeared on top of the absolute positioned elements - it shouldn't but just to be safe */
}


/* the slideshow */

.zd-slider #img_01 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;
}

.zd-slider #img_02 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;
}

.zd-slider #img_03 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autoplay {
  4%,
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    z-index: 2; /* add this to make sure visible item has a higher z-index that none visible items */
  }
  0%,
  37%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    z-index: 1; /* add this to make sure visible item has a higher z-index that none visible items */
  }
}

@keyframes autoplay {
  4%,
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    z-index: 2; /* add this to make sure visible item has a higher z-index that none visible items */
  }
  0%,
  37%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    ] z-index: 1; /* add this to make sure visible item has a higher z-index that none visible items */
  }
}


/* the slide timing indicator */

.zd-slider #slide {
  width: 98px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: slide 3s linear infinite;
  animation: slide linear 3s infinite;
  z-index: 3; /* make slider appear above images */
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="zd-container" id="zd-collection2">
  <div class="zd-slider">

    <!-- sizing div doesn't need container class-->
    <span id="blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /></span>


    <span class="container" id="img_01"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /></span>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="container" id="img_02"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x135" alt="" /></a>
    <span class="container" id="img_03"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /></span>
    <div id="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below css property

`.zd-slider a {
    display: inline-block;
}`

Becasue the `a` tag is not getting any width or height, may be unable to explain you properly, try this one and will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from your `position: absolute`.

It remove all images from the normal flow. So the `<a/>` tag don't "contain" the image.

You can try with a static position and a `transform: translate` animation instead of `opacity` so the images don't need to be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

This works, need to apply position, width, height and z-index, all of them to the link:

```css
   #img_02_link{
     position: absolute; 
     top:0; left:0; 
     width: 100%; 
     height: 100%; 
     z-index:1;
  }

    .zd-slider { position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin-top: 0px; }
    .zd-slider img[id*="img"] {width:100%; position:absolute; left:0; top:0; opacity:0; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}

    /* set the width/height of the slideshow */
    .zd-slider img#blank {display:block; width:100%; visibility:hidden;}

    /* the slideshow */
    .zd-slider #img_01 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;}
    .zd-slider #img_02 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;}
    .zd-slider #img_03 {-webkit-animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s; animation:autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s; }


    @-webkit-keyframes autoplay {
      4%,33% {opacity:1;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
      0%,37%,100% {opacity:0;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}
    }


    @keyframes autoplay {
      4%,33% {opacity:1;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
      0%,37%,100% {opacity:0;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";}
    }

    /* the slide timing indicator */
    .zd-slider #slide {width:98px; height:5px; position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    -webkit-animation:slide 3s linear infinite; animation:slide linear 3s infinite;}

    @keyframes slide {
      0% {left:-100px;}
      100% {left:100%;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide {
      0% {left:-100px;}
      100% {left:100%;}
    }
```

```html
  <div class="zd-container" id="zd-collection2"> <div class="zd-slider">

   <img id="blank" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> 
   
   <img id="img_01" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> 
   
   <a id="img_02_link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <img id="img_02" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" />
   </a>
   
   <img id="img_03" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133" alt="" /> 

   <div id="slide"></div> 
  </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate div for each slider images and give Z-index to that common class div....

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yc07b60j/

```css
.zd-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.zd-slider a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.zd-slider img[id*="img"] {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}


/* set the width/height of the slideshow */

.zd-slider img#blank {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* the slideshow */

.zd-slider #img_01 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 0s;
}

.zd-slider #img_02 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 3s;
}

.zd-slider #img_03 {
  -webkit-animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s;
  animation: autoplay 9s linear infinite 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autoplay {
  4%,
  33% {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  0%,
  37%,
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}

@keyframes autoplay {
  4%,
  33% {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  }
  0%,
  37%,
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  }
}


/* the slide timing indicator */

.zd-slider #slide {
  width: 98px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-animation: slide 3s linear infinite;
  animation: slide linear 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="zd-container" id="zd-collection2">
  <div class="zd-slider">

    <img id="blank" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133/f44242/ffffff" alt="" />

    <img id="img_01" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133/86f441/ffffff" alt="" />

    <a href="http://www.google.com">
      <img id="img_02" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133/f44242/ffffff" alt="" />
    </a>

    <img id="img_03" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1440x133/41aff4/ffffff" alt="" />
    
  </div>
</div>
```